# How to Retrive data from json post method through mvc controller web services using NSURLSESSION?

Tags: objective-c

first of all please, click on this [link](http://ios.skyzon.in/STudent/STudentDetail?grno=324) then...

How I'm getting this output like name ,std  & assign to textbox I'm already done this in xcode 5 but NSURLCOnnection not used in xcode 7.2 so Using NSURLSESSION How Can I bind to textbox??

```
    NSError *error = nil;


    NSMutableDictionary *dic2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [dic2 setObject:@"324" forKey:@"grno"];


    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [dic setObject:@"RestAPI" forKey:@"interface"];

    [dic setObject:@"StudentLogin" forKey:@"method"];

    [dic setObject:dic2  forKey:@"parameters"];


    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];


    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ios.skyzon.in/STudent/STudentDetail"]];

    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [req setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:req

    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);

            if(error == nil)

            {

                    // NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                    // NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);

                    NSMutableDictionary *responseDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

                    responseDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:postData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

                    NSLog(@"%@",responseDic);

                    self.txt.text = [responseDic objectForKey:@"Name"];

                    NSLog(@"%@",[responseDic objectForKey:@"Name"]);

            }

    }];

    [dataTask resume];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you NSURLSESSION  like below.

```
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ios.skyzon.in/STudent/STudentDetail"] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
 self.txt.text = [responseDic objectForKey:@"Name"];

    }];
```

May be it will help you.